# Register nib with collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, xib

I have FeedCell.swift and FeedCell.xib, in feedcell xib i set cell custom class to 'FeedCell'

Code in view controller viewDidLoad

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "FeedCell", bundle: .main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "feedCell")
```

**Problem**:

I want to subclass FeedCell and use that class with collectionView
Like:

```
class FeedCell:UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var showImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var showIconImageView: UIImageView!

}

class AppFeedCell: FeedCell { 
    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       // configure cell
    }
}
```

How to register/use FeedCell and AppFeedCell with collectionview?

Answer (score 18):

If your **AppFeedCell** have a different UI Configuration, for example it does not bind some IBOutlets defined in **FeedCell** or it adds new ones not present in it's superclass, then you will have to register both Nibs (asuming you have two separated Nib files)

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "FeedCell", bundle: .main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "feedCell")
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "AppFeedCell", bundle: .main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "appFeedCell")
```

And then you will be able to dequeue each one when you need.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if you_need_AppFeedCell {
        let cell : AppFeedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("appFeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AppFeedCell
        return cell
    } else
        let cell : FeedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("feedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

This way you may have two different Nib files even if **AppFeedCell** subclass **FeedCell**.

Otherwise, if both class and subclass share the same cell layout and outlets, then simply by casting the dequeued cell (**FeedCell**) to **AppFeedCell** should be enough, without registering another Nib, as *Taras Chernyshenko* pointed above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to register separate xib for AppFeedCell. You already registered nib to your collectionView.

Just dequeue cell and cast it to needed class in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath 
    indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
if you_need_AppFeedCell {
    let cell : AppFeedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("feedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AppFeedCell
    return cell
} else
    let cell : FeedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("feedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedCell
    return cell
}
}
```

Your `AppFeedCell` will inherit all outlets from `FeedCell` so it should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your cell xib/storyboard go to **Identity inspector** set **class: AppFeedCell**

Now in Datasource Methods of collectionview you can create cell of type AppFeedCell.

Comment: So i have to create new xib?

Comment: No just set class type = AppFeedCell instead of FeedCell

Comment: But i m also using FeedCell

Comment: If you are subclassing FeedCell that means you are inheriting class to AppFeedCell where you can use all properties and methods of FeedCell.

Comment: i know that, but how to register and use both cell in same collectionview

Comment: If you want to use both cell then you need to create separate xib for AppFeedCell and need to register 2 cells. And you can use these cells with `if {...)else{...}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164266/discussion-between-priya-and-spatel).

Comment: @SPatel not create new bt use with if condition and user identifier are both same.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell : AppFeedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("your_reusable_identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AppFeedCell


    return cell
}
```

Comment: How to register AppFeedCell with collectionView

Comment: @SPatel Go to your xib, select the xib and set its class as AppFeedCell.

Comment: I did it for FeedCell

Comment: Please tell what you want exactly.

Comment: I want both cell in my collectionview

Comment: but you can use AppFeedCell as class in FeedCell not UICollectionViewCell so you can use AppFeedCell as a subclass FeedCell.

Comment: self.yourcollectionview.register(AppFeedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "your_reusable_identifier") // did you try this?

Comment: So how to register and dequee botth cell?

Comment: if you want in your collectionview then why its parent class is FeedCell?

Comment: @SelvamSankaran it not work , i get all property nil

Comment: @SelvamSankaran im using xib'